# Add Checkbox input with required validation

Tags: magento-2.1, checkbox

I want to add a checkbox with a required field.

My code is :

```
<div>
    <input class="input required-entry" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" />  I agree to the Terms and Conditions.
</div>
```

But it's not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` in your form

```
<form id="custom-form" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <input class="input required-entry" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" />  I agree to the Terms and Conditions.
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
```

Or

```
<form id="custom-form">
    <input class="input required-entry" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" />  I agree to the Terms and Conditions.
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, can we display alert?

Comment: What do you mean by alert and where ?

Comment: When I click on submit if checkbox is uncheck then i want to display alert ex plz agree terms and conditions.

Comment: `if(jQuery('#check').not(':checked').length){
    alert('Not checked');
}`

Comment: I tried but this code is not working

Comment: Check you console maybe you have some js errors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vnkg1qwx/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82786/discussion-between-gill-and-prince).